# Boost::map erase() makes iterator invalid

Tags: boost, shared-memory, erase

I am using boost shared memory and have a map of (key,value). Using below code I try to iterate through map and delete the entries. Crash is seen intermittently.

```
for (int_vector::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); /* BLANK */){
  if (*it == 1) //some condition
  {
     it = v.erase(it);
  } 
else {
     ++it;
  }
```

}

What is wrong in above code? Crash is seen only sometimes in rbtree_best_fit.hpp

Comment: Is it a vector or a map, now? Also, your problem is likely a lack of synchronization

Answer (score 0):

As you are using shared memory I guess you have more than a single process/thread accessing the vector. If you are not using synchronization (there is a mutex in the same library) it can well be that the vector gets corrupted by one process while it is being traversed by another process.

Above considerations aside, your code would be correct in a single threaded environment and if you are single threaded then the next natural step is to run the program under Valgrind.

Comment: thanks!! I am taking care of synchronization by using scoped lock on shared memory.